# URL Blocked using Facebook passport auth (React + Node.js)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, facebook

Basically I recently deployed my web app backend to heroku to get the following link: https://crop-disease-backend.herokuapp.com/ so I configured my routes accordingly.

**The ERROR MESSAGE**

```
URL blocked
This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not white-listed in the app's client OAuth settings. Make sure that the client and web OAuth logins are on and add all your app domains as valid OAuth redirect URIs.
```

I know the problem is on facebook developer console because when it was hosted on the local host all was working perfectly.

Below is an image that shows my facebook dev console settings.
[image: My Facebook Developer Console Settings]

**This is my routes related to the facebook auth**

```
app.get('/auth/facebook',
  passport.authenticate('facebook'));

  app.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
  passport.authenticate('facebook', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function(req, res) {
    // Successful authentication, redirect home.
    res.redirect('http://localhost:3000/home');
  });
```

On the react front-end, the login button has the following onClick

```
const facebookLogin = () => {
    window.open("https://crop-disease-backend.herokuapp.com/auth/facebook" , "_self")
  }
```

Is what I have input in the facebook developer console correct? or something is wrong because I am certain that it has to do with that. Does it also have to do with the fact that my app mode is in development?

Comment: Did you add the uri in the config where you also put credentials?

Comment: Yes, the ClientId and Client Secret as well as the callback which is callbackURL: "/auth/facebook/callback"

Comment: I'm pretty sure it should be the full url, not only the path

Comment: @Konrad I fixed it and posted the solution below, I had to add the config url to the vali Oauth Redirect uri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix it. Basically the uri in the config was "/auth/facebook/callback" and This uri was not included under valid Oauth Redirect URLs so i needed to add that in the valid Oauth Redirect URLs section like so:

https://crop-disease-backend.herokuapp.com/auth/facebook/callback

Now it works like a charm.